# Understanding double precision operations in C

Tags: c, types, precision, double-precision

I would like to understand why this code:

```
double r,d,rc;
scanf("%lf %lf", &r, &d);
rc = (r * r) - (d/2) * (d/2);
printf("%.2f\n", M_PI * rc);
```

returns more precise result than this one (without `rc` variable assignment):

```
double r,d,rc;
scanf("%lf %lf", &r, &d);
printf("%.2f\n", M_PI * (r * r) - (d/2) * (d/2));
```

Another, related, question: why is `n * n` better than `pow(n,2)`?

Comment: Then read this — http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Seriously, that article has to pop up automatically along with possible duplicates...

Comment: The results are definitely exactly equally *precise*. The question is which one is more *accurate*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first code sample computes:

```
M_PI * ((r * r) - (d/2) * (d/2));
```

The second computes:

```
(M_PI * (r * r)) - (d/2) * (d/2);
```

A call to `pow(n, 2)` is the same as `n * n`, on most compilers.  The *exact same* assembly will be emitted.  This is due to an optimization called "strength reduction" -- most `pow()` implementations will check to see if the exponent is 2, and reduce that case to a single multiplication. The unoptimized version is slightly more expensive since it requires a function call and some branching.

Note that `M_PI` is not part of the C standard, so you can use the equivalent, which compiles to the exact same code:

```
double M_PI = 4.0 * atan(1.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second question; `pow` is designed to perform arbitrary powers, but it shouldn't be surprising that there is a faster way to compute the answer when the power is constant.  A single multiplication is fast (just a single processor instruction), whereas a call to `pow` requires function call overhead (ignoring optimisation for now) and an iterative algorithm which repeatedly multiplies until it gets the answer.  When you can see a mathematical shortcut to avoid such things, you use it.